# 2D N body simulation

Tags: python, algorithm, simulation, physics

I've followed the equations from the n-body problem found on Wikipedia and implemented a simple O(n²) n-body simulation. However, once I visualize the simulation, things don't behave as expected, namely, all the particles move away from the center as though they have high repulsive force. I thought at first I may have mistaken the direction of the force vectors, but I tried flipping it and it did pretty much the same thing.

```
data = np.random.rand(100, 2)

velocities = np.zeros_like(data)
masses = np.ones_like(data)
dt = 60 * 60 * 24


for _ in range(10000):
    forces = np.zeros_like(data)

    for i, node1 in enumerate(data):
        for j, node2 in enumerate(data):
            d = node2 - node1
            # First term is gravitational constant, 1e-8 is a softening factor
            forces[i] += 6.67384e-11 * d / (np.sqrt(d.dot(d) + 1e-8) ** 3)

    velocities += forces * dt / masses
    data += velocities * dt

    yield data  # for visualization
```

I also considered that it may just not work in 2D (although there is no reason it shouldn't at all, so I tried it in 3D as well by setting rand dimensions to (100, 3), but the behaviour was the same.

I've looked over other code available online, but I can't seem to find what I've done wrong (or differently from others), so any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT 1**
This actually appears to be consistent with the equations. I've worked out the first couple steps by hand for [-1, 1] and [1, 1] (ignoring G) and for p1, the forces are [0.25, 0.7, 81, 0, 0] respectively. However, since the velocity is so high from the third step, and that particle p2 does the opposite of p1, they move away really fast. However, other implementations easily found online don't face this issue. I can't seem to figure out why. I thought it may have been the initialization, but other implementations don't seem to suffer from this.

Comment: You should do some debugging.  Step through the code for a very simple example (e.g. two bodies) to see where the behaviour diverges from expectations.

Comment: I've done a fair bit of debugging, in fact this is my debugging code. It diverges for the simplest case of 2 bodies, where they are apparently repelled (for either direction of the force vector). My guess is that I must be missing some key part of the update rules, but I can't seem to find what I'm missing or have written incorrectly.

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that for two bodies, you ought to be able to reason about the behaviour on a frame-by-frame basis (you could even compute it by hand) - does everything move in the correct direction in, say, the first frame?

Comment: I've gone through a couple of steps by hand now and it seems that for the simplest case [-1, 1], [1, 1], the forces on p1 = [0.25, 0.7, 81, 0, 0]. So this is actually expected behaviour? However the velocity is still really high so it keeps moving away. The other particle does the opposite, so they move away from each other. This begs the question, how come the other implementations that we can find online don't have this issue? I see no principled way to get around this, yet others seem to have done it easily.

Comment: Perhaps your timestep is too large?  With two bodies starting with zero initial conditions, I believe the expected behaviour is for them to oscillate indefinitely (basically a pendulum).  If your timestep is greater than the oscillation period, things are going to go awry.

Comment: In fact to [solve differential equations accurately with Euler integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations) (which is what you're doing) requires the time step to be small compared to changes occurring in the solution. The time step must be much less than the period of oscillation.

Comment: You arent checking for i != j? Even with smoothening, it will apply a huge force and may look like repulsion when they cross over beyond each others centers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My dt was too large. Setting the dt to a smaller value e.g. 0.05 did it.

Comment: I'd also recommend using RK4 instead of the Euler method.